# Product of Paracompact spaces being Paracompact

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, alternative-proof, infinite-games, paracompactness

I'm interested in the game-characterization proposed by Telgarsky ([paper](https://eudml.org/doc/214826)) of the class of paracompact spaces that preserve paracompactness under cartesian product with another paracompact space. He uses a game $G(\mathbb{DC},X)$ defined over the class of disjoint unions of compact sets. In particular I'm interested only in the proved implication, that is:

> If X is paracompact and $\mathbb{DC}$-like, then X × Y is paracompact for all
>   paracompact spaces Y .

*Telgársky, Rastislav*, [**Spaces defined by topological games**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4064/fm-88-3-193-223), Fundam. Math. 88, 193-223 (1975). [ZBL0311.54025](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0311.54025).)

Do you know if the proof of this theorem appears in a somewhat more intelligible and elegant way in a more recent paper\presentation\notes etc.? Thanks

Comment: Thm 14.8 right? What's wrong with the paper? It seems readable enough, if you take the time for it.

Comment: I think it is 14.6. The fact is that I would have to insert it in a presentation, so either it's concise and somewhat listenable, or I have to skip the proof.

Comment: 14.8 is more well-known, I think. "listenable"? never a criterion for maths.

Comment: [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1158765/4280), shows that Morita's classical work is pretty close to this (without the games) and that has been covered in many other papers.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, thanks for this pearl of wisdom.

Comment: However, I'm strictly interested in this infinite-game result